# How do I restore system default settings on Linux Mint KDE?

Tags: linux, fonts, restore, linux-mint

I did something weird and now my text size is like 3pt on every system window, but when I go in and change my window fonts to larger to something that looks normal, it makes my clock, bash, and other fonts absolutely gigantic. Is there any way I can just roll back my system and it's settings? It wouldn't be much bother as I installed the OS yesterday. I'd hate to have to reinstall entirely though, but I guess it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

To keep in the paradigm, create a shell script with 3 commands

```
kquitapp plasma-desktop
rm .kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc
kshell4 plasma-desktop
```

In Mint's KDE, the file will need to be removed from this path instead:

```
rm .usr/share/mintkde-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/plasma-destop-appletsrc
```